# Create table in dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have got a dynamic query witch create a table with two fields. The first field is from #Table and the second (CreateDate) is addes in static way.

```
if object_id(N'tempdb..#Table') is not null
    drop table #Table;

    create table #Table
    (

        [SchemaName] nvarchar(100) not null
        ,[TableName] nvarchar(128) not null
        ,[FieldId] int  
        ,[ColumnName] nvarchar(100)
        ,FieldDefinitionID int
        ,Ordinal int 
        ,[Data Type] nvarchar(100)
        ,IsNullable bit
        ,IsIdentity bit
        ,HasDefault bit 
        ,DefaultName nvarchar(100)
        ,DefaultDefinition  nvarchar(100)
        ,[Description] nvarchar(100) 
        ,HasCheckConstraint bit  
        ,CheckConstraintName bit 
        ,CheckConstraintDefinition bit 
        ,PartitionIndexKey bit 
        ,ObjectID int 


    );



    insert into #Table
                (
                    [SchemaName] 
                    ,[TableName] 
                    ,[FieldId]   
                    ,[ColumnName]   
                    ,Ordinal 
                    ,[Data Type] 
                    ,IsNullable 
                    ,IsIdentity
                    ,HasDefault 
                    ,HasCheckConstraint
                )
                select 
                N'dbo'
                ,N'test'
                ,-6
                ,N'RecordId'
                ,1
                ,N'int'
                ,0
                ,0
                ,0
                ,0






    insert into #Table
                (
                    [SchemaName] 
                    ,[TableName] 
                    ,[FieldId]   
                    ,[ColumnName]   
                    ,Ordinal 
                    ,[Data Type] 
                    ,IsNullable 
                    ,IsIdentity
                    ,HasDefault 
                    ,HasCheckConstraint
                )
                select 
                N'dbo'
                ,N'test'
                ,-6
                ,N'RecordId'
                ,1
                ,N'int'
                ,0
                ,0
                ,0
                ,0






select          N'

create table [' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'].[' + [t].[TableName] + N']
(
    [' 
    + [t].[ColumnName] 
    + N'] ' 
    + [t].[Data Type] 
    + case
        when [t].[IsNullable] = 0
        then N' not null '
        else N' null '
    end
    + case
        when [t].[IsIdentity] = 1
        then N' identity '
        else N''
    end
    + case
        when [t].[HasDefault] = 1
        then N' constraint [' + [t].[DefaultName] + N'] default ' + [t].[DefaultDefinition]
        else N''
    end
    +
    N'
    ,[CreateDate] datetime not null
);

exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''EntityId''
                                ,@value = N''' + cast(11 as nvarchar(max)) + N'''
                                ,@level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = N''' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'''
                                ,@level1type = N''Table'', @level1name = N''' + [t].[TableName] + N''';

exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''MessageId''
                                ,@value = N''' + cast(3456 as nvarchar(max)) + N'''
                                ,@level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = N''' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'''
                                ,@level1type = N''Table'', @level1name = N''' + [t].[TableName] + N''';

' 
from  #Table t
```

So the result is this create statment:

```
 create table [dbo].[test]
    (
        [RecordId] int not null 
        ,[CreateDate] datetime not null
    );

    exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'EntityId'
                                    ,@value = N'11'
                                    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = N'dbo'
                                    ,@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = N'test';

    exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MessageId'
                                    ,@value = N'3456'
                                    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = N'dbo'
                                    ,@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = N'test';
```

I want to have the same result but I need to get a second field in dynamic way from #Table just like the first field. But I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: How many fields #Table have?

Answer (score 0):

Add a record to `#Table` with the data of the new field before you execute your query.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO #Table ([SchemaName], [TableName], [ColumnName], [Data Type])
VALUES ('dbo', 'Test', 'MyNewField', 'MyNewFieldType');
```

You need to fill in the correct values for the field name and its data type. Optionally, you also might need to set explicit values for the nullability, identity, default, etc.

However, you have not specified the structure of `#Table`. I derived the fields from your query, but it might be the case, that you need to include additional fields as well.

Comment: I add structure of #Table to my post. But how to edit my query to get dynamicly second field to create statment?

Comment: That already happens. The last query of your script (that generates the dynamic SQL) is in fact a SELECT query on `#Table`. So it will process all records from `#Table`.

Comment: You are inserting two records into `#Table` now, but it seems that both INSERT queries are inserting the same data. You probably want to fix your second INSERT query so that it inserts the data for the new field you want to include in the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
create table #Table
(
    [SchemaName] nvarchar(100) not null
    ,[TableName] nvarchar(128) not null
    ,[FieldId] int  
    ,[ColumnName] nvarchar(100)
    ,FieldDefinitionID int
    ,Ordinal int 
    ,[Data Type] nvarchar(100)
    ,IsNullable bit
    ,IsIdentity bit
    ,HasDefault bit 
    ,DefaultName nvarchar(100)
    ,DefaultDefinition  nvarchar(100)
    ,[Description] nvarchar(100) 
    ,HasCheckConstraint bit  
    ,CheckConstraintName bit 
    ,CheckConstraintDefinition bit 
    ,PartitionIndexKey bit 
    ,ObjectID int 
);
GO

insert into #Table
(
    [SchemaName] 
    ,[TableName] 
    ,[FieldId]   
    ,[ColumnName]   
    ,Ordinal 
    ,[Data Type] 
    ,IsNullable 
    ,IsIdentity
    ,HasDefault 
    ,HasCheckConstraint
)
values
(
    N'dbo'
    ,N'test'
    ,-6
    ,N'RecordId'
    ,1
    ,N'int'
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
);

insert into #Table
(
    [SchemaName] 
    ,[TableName] 
    ,[FieldId]   
    ,[ColumnName]   
    ,Ordinal 
    ,[Data Type] 
    ,IsNullable 
    ,IsIdentity
    ,HasDefault 
    ,HasCheckConstraint
)
values
(
    N'dbo'
    ,N'test'
    ,-6
    ,N'NewField'
    ,2
    ,N'NewFieldType'
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
    ,0
);
GO

declare @NewLine nchar(2) = nchar(13) + nchar(10);

with [Tables] AS
(
    select distinct
        [SchemaName],
        [TableName],
        N'[' + [SchemaName] + N'].[' + [TableName] + N']' AS [FullTableName]
    from
        #Table
)
select
    N'create table ' + [FullTableName] + @NewLine +
    N'(' + @NewLine +
    N'    ' + REPLACE(STUFF((select
                                 N',[' + [ColumnName] + N'] '
                                 + [Data Type] +
                                 + case when [IsNullable] = 0 then N' not null' else N' null' end
                                 + case when [IsIdentity] = 1 then N' identity' else N'' end
                                 + case when [HasDefault] = 1 then N' constraint [' + [DefaultName] + N'] default ' + [DefaultDefinition] else N'' end
                             from
                                 #Table
                             where
                                 [SchemaName] = T.[SchemaName] AND
                                 [TableName] = T.[TableName]
                             order by
                                 [Ordinal]
                             for xml path('')
                            ), 1, 1, N''
                      ), N',', @NewLine + N'    ,') + @NewLine +
    N'    ,[CreateDate] datetime not null' + @NewLine +
    N');' + @NewLine +
    @NewLine +
    N'exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''EntityId''' + @NewLine +
    N'                                ,@value = N''' + cast(11 as nvarchar(max)) + N'''' + @NewLine +
    N'                                ,@level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = N''' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'''' + @NewLine +
    N'                                ,@level1type = N''Table'', @level1name = N''' + [t].[TableName] + N''';' + @NewLine +
    @NewLine +
    N'exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''MessageId''' + @NewLine +
    N'                                ,@value = N''' + cast(3456 as nvarchar(max)) + N'''' + @NewLine +
    N'                                ,@level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = N''' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'''' + @NewLine +
    N'                                ,@level1type = N''Table'', @level1name = N''' + [t].[TableName] + N''';' + @NewLine
from
    [Tables] as T
order by
    T.[SchemaName],
    T.[TableName];
```